# I need this conditional formatting formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

Basically I want to write a conditional formatting equation on Google Sheets that will check if a formula is being executed consectveiy down a column?
e.g.
in column D I have the following equation from rows 4-10
=concatanate(A4&"*"&B4&"*"&C4)
and this is applied to row 10.

I want to write a conditional formatting that checks that at every row the cells are referencing the row it's in. So at row 8 it should be A8&"*"&B8&"*"&C8. I want to know if it's not consecutive down the column if that makes sense so if at row 8 it's A9&"*"&B9&"*"&C9 instead then I want it to highlight red.

$A4 & "*" & $B4 & "*" & $C4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Apply to range***: `D4:D10`

***Custom formula is***:

```
=--regexextract(formulatext(D4),"\d+")<>row()
```

***Scenario 2***:

*to check if output by formula in column_E is matching with what it ideally should've been for that specific row → if **NOT** → highlight*

```
=len($E2)*($E2<>"https"&join("_",offset(indirect("A"&row()),,,,3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! that worked for me :) it highlighted ones that were not consecutive. If I also had to write a formula where I had to check if that formula was being executed correctly would it be of any value to add a conditional formatting rule with the following: =$A4 & "" & $B4 & "" & $C4

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AhpBRzhlzUHc2IKZq6ID16LHsXp6sLxldsuKTGcAZRU/edit#gid=2100307022

there are two tings I want to check:
1. in rowE I want to add a conditional format that just checks if the formula is being executed correctly so its concatanated them correctly.

2. in my OG spreadsheet I have a lot of cells which are pulled into create a long piece of string (recreated simply in rowF) I want to check if text from two strings is referenced in that string. my issue is, doesn't the answer change when I change the info in the cells? so how can I check if it's refernced?

Comment: thank you so much for your help I appreciate it :) can =--regexextract(formulatext(D4),"\d+")<>row() be applied to any range and it would work if I just changed the 'D4' part ?

Comment: yes just change `D` to whichever column range has the formula